# Django CSRF "Referer Malformed"... but it isn't

Tags: django, nginx, csrf, uwsgi, referer

I'm trying to test a deployment config for a Django setup that works fine in development mode.

I have name-based routing via Nginx's `ssl_preread` module on a load balancer, and SSL terminates at another Nginx instance on the server itself where the requests are proxied to uwsgi by socket.

```
server {
    server_name dev.domain.net;
    listen 80 proxy_protocol;
    listen [::]:80 proxy_protocol;
        location / {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}
server {
    server_name dev.domain.net;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/website.sock;
    }
    location /favicon.ico {
        access_log off; log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

I have uwsgi set to log `%(host)` and `%(referer)`, they match in the logs.

In my uwsgi_params I'm passing `$host` and `$referer` like so, since I'm using name-based routing I pick up the `$server_name` variable that triggered the Nginx response...

```
uwsgi_param  HTTP_REFERER       $server_name;
uwsgi_param  HTTP_HOST          $host;
```

Adding (or taking away) protocols and ports to these makes no difference.  Taking them away predictably generates a Django `ALLOWED_HOSTS` debug error.

I've confirmed that my `ALLOWED_HOSTS` includes the `$host`. I've tried adding `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` for the same `$host` variable. I've tried setting `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN` for the same `$host` variable. I have `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE` set to True per the docs recommendation.

No matter what combination of the above settings are used, I get:

`Referer checking failed - Referer is malformed.` on all POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: don't use the uwsgi unix socket, but rather use `http-socket` and send the  proxy request to localhost over unencrypted http (in uwsgi ini file):

```
http-socket = 127.0.0.1:8001
```

In nginx, get rid of uwsgi proxy params and simply `proxy_pass` with `proxy_protocol` headers enabled:

```
server {
    server_name dev.domain.net;
    listen 443 ssl proxy_protocol;
    listen [::]:443 ssl proxy_protocol;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    }
    location /favicon.ico {
        access_log off; log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

At that point you can enable all of the recommended deployment settings in the Django docs, explicitly declare your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` and everything works fine.

These are a quite silly series of hoops with no apparent correct set of answers, especially considering referers are client headers that are easily forged.

The better answer is Django needs to get rid of a client referer check in its CSRF mechanism, it's pointless and makes no sense...