# Django password reset token doesn't work after upgrade to v3.1?

Tags: python, django, token, password-hash

I'm scratching my head on this one all day.

I have a Wagtail site that was previously running on Django 2.2 that I'm in the process of upgrading to Django 3.1.  I'm using the Django internal password reset token functions to generate unsubscribe links for marketing email being sent through Django.

Since six was deprecated in 3.x versions of Django I've had to re-write my repurposing of the one-time login links a bit, and despite mimicking the behavior of Django internally the view simply doesn't work, *despite working manually in the shell.* The last bit is the kicker, if I input the values manually and step through my code in the shell, it seems to work.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_decode
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator

UserModel = get_user_model()


def unsubscribe(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64).decode()
        user = UserModel.objects.get(email=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, UserModel.DoesNotExist, ValidationError):
        user = None
    if user is not None:
        token_generator = default_token_generator
        if token_generator.check_token(user, token):
            # If valid token, set is_subscribed = False and show confirmation.
            user.is_subscribed = False
            user.save()
            return render(request, 'account/unsubscribe.html')
        else:
            # Else, return invalid token page.
            return render(request, 'account/invalid.html')
```

If I click on an unsubscribe link in an email, I always get returned to my "invalid token" page with the above view, and the user is not set to false on `is_subscribed`.

However, if I run through the same function manually, the token comes back True.

```
>>> uid = 'me@gmail.com'
>>> user = UserModel.objects.get(email=uid)
>>> token_generator = default_token_generator
>>> token_generator.check_token(user, token='an08ff-atoken123456789020f3b65c9')
True
```

So the only thing that can be wrong here is that conditional if on `check_token` must not be coming back True for some reason, but why? When it works manually?

Comment: Could you add a `print('token')` at the top of the `unsubscribe` function and show the output here? To check whether the token is passed properly, I mean.

Comment: Yep, did that, it is, as is the user.  Really baffling why this doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

I traced this bug today and found that **UWSGI** is breaking it. When I launched my server using production settings without uwsgi, it worked fine.

This is an interesting catch-22 considering [Django's CSRF implementation doesn't work properly with SSL-passthrough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67575288/django-csrf-referer-malformed-but-it-isnt) on sockets, from what I can tell, and now I find that tokens don't work on HTTP-passthrough without SSL.

joy...